Mapping the timestamp data type to PostgreSQL in a query
I have a problem, maybe someone has encountered this, I can’t make a request that can work with null correctly.
I have an entity in the database with a column updateAt.
@Data
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(name = "entity")
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "ENUM", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "DURATION", typeClass = PostgreSQLIntervalType.class)
})
public class EntityTypeMetaData implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TemplateStatus status;
    

And I have a SQL query that select all entities that have column  updateAt between passed parameters, and filtering by status:
public interface JpaEntityTypeMetadataRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityTypeMetaData,Long> {
 @Query("""
    SELECT em FROM EntityTypeMetaData em
    WHERE (:states IS NULL OR em.status IN :states)
    AND (em.updatedAt BETWEEN :from AND :to)
    """)
    Page<EntityTypeMetaData> findTemplatesByStatusAndUpdatePeriod(
            @Param("states") List<TemplateStatus> states,
            @Param("from") Date from,
            @Param("to") Date to,
            Pageable pageable
    );
}

Here I have a search for entities from the database for which the UpdateAt column is in the passed range and in the passed status data.
This all works correctly, but I have a requirement for a null check for the "from" and "to" parameters.
I have such a check for the "Status" parameter
And if null is passed here, then this filtering does not work and all entities with different statuses are displayed.
But if you add the same check for the to and from columns:
@Query("""
    SELECT em FROM EntityTypeMetaData em
    WHERE (:states IS NULL OR em.status IN :states)
    AND (:from IS NULL OR em.updatedAt >= :from)
    AND (:to IS NULL OR em.updatedAt <= :to)
    """)
Page<EntityTypeMetaData> findTemplatesByStatusAndUpdatePeriod(
        @Param("states") List<TemplateStatus> states,
        @Param("from") Date from,
        @Param("to") Date to,
        Pageable pageable
);

I get a http 500 exception.
I see this entry in the logs:
 ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $3
2024-11-27 14:52:31.427 ERROR [,13c240aa8dcee382,13c240aa8dcee382] 5308 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] r.s.p.sd.handler.SdRestExceptionHandler  : Request with trace id: 13c240aa8dcee382 exception:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $3
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)

Hibernate can't make this request because it can't determine the type when checking for null.
It complains about the third parameter in the request, and the third parameter in the request is from, since the first two are status, this is done by a certain setting that does this for the speed of query execution.
But here the essence of the problem is that hibernate can't make this check.
Maybe someone has encountered this and can help in creating this request with a check for null

I can't answer the specific question, but will make two observations: a) you are using names which are dangerously close to reserved words for your datetime parameters and b) you seem to be using obsolete datetime types (java.util.Date[?]). Fixing might even solve your actual problem but should probably be done anyway

Use Instant or OffsetDateTime in Java for your updatedAt attribute. And map to a timestamp with time zone in the database. As @g00se already said, Date is obsolescent. It was also very poorly designed and has caused a lot of problems over the years, so this is good so.

It has to be said that Instant is not yet officially supported by JDBC but OffsetDateTime is good with a column type of timestamp with time zone. Of course 'time zone' here really means 'offset from UTC'

Edit your Question to state which of the two Date classes are you using.  And, you shouldn’t be using either one. They are both supplanted by modern java.time classes.

Edit your Question to state exactly the data type of your date-time column in Postgres.

@g00se While that is true, I don‘t remember whether it‘s a different story for Hibernate. The OP will need to use one that works, obviously, and I trust at least one of them does.

Not sure, but I don't see how Hibernate would be exempt from adherence to the current JDBC standard

Solution 1: Explicit Type Casting
You can cast the parameters :from and :to to a specific type in the query. For example:
@Query("""
    SELECT em FROM EntityTypeMetaData em
    WHERE (:states IS NULL OR em.status IN :states)
    AND (:from IS NULL OR em.updatedAt >= CAST(:from AS timestamp))
    AND (:to IS NULL OR em.updatedAt <= CAST(:to AS timestamp))
    """)
Page<EntityTypeMetaData> findTemplatesByStatusAndUpdatePeriod(
        @Param("states") List<TemplateStatus> states,
        @Param("from") Date from,
        @Param("to") Date to,
        Pageable pageable
);

In this case, CAST(:from AS timestamp) ensures PostgreSQL knows the type of :from and :to as timestamp.
Solution 2: Conditional Parameters in Query Logic
You can split the query into multiple parts dynamically. Use Spring Data JPA's @Query combined with a dynamic query builder using Spring Specifications or QueryDSL.
For instance:
public interface JpaEntityTypeMetadataRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityTypeMetaData, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<EntityTypeMetaData> {
}

// Specification
public static Specification<EntityTypeMetaData> withDynamicFilters(List<TemplateStatus> states, Date from, Date to) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        
        if (states != null) {
            predicates.add(root.get("status").in(states));
        }
        if (from != null) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("updatedAt"), from));
        }
        if (to != null) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("updatedAt"), to));
        }
        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}

You can then use this specification:
Page<EntityTypeMetaData> results = repository.findAll(
    EntityTypeMetaDataSpecifications.withDynamicFilters(states, from, to),
    pageable
);

This avoids the parameter typing issue entirely by building the query dynamically.
Solution 3: Use Native Query
If you prefer using native SQL, you can pass the query directly and handle null checks explicitly:
@Query(value = """
    SELECT * FROM entity
    WHERE (:states IS NULL OR status IN (:states))
    AND (:from IS NULL OR updated_at >= :from::timestamp)
    AND (:to IS NULL OR updated_at <= :to::timestamp)
    """, nativeQuery = true)
Page<EntityTypeMetaData> findTemplatesByStatusAndUpdatePeriodNative(
        @Param("states") List<TemplateStatus> states,
        @Param("from") Date from,
        @Param("to") Date to,
        Pageable pageable
);

This approach also uses explicit type casting (::timestamp) to ensure PostgreSQL correctly handles NULL parameters.
